# Display releated tables on the same page in widget like admin's "filter_horizontal"

Tags: django, django-views, many-to-many, models

Lets say that I have 2 models in DB with relation m2m (Question and Questionnaire). I need to make something like admin's [filter_horizontal](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html) but with one difference. In the left table, I want to have all questions in DB. On the top of right table should be combo box with questionnaires. After chosing custom questionnaire, all questions which are releated with that questionnaire will be presented below in right table. Buttons between those tables will be used for adding and removing questions from chosen questionnaire. Is it possible to build? If yes, please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).  This includes add and delete forms.